# unity integration with react-native

Tags: react-native, unity-game-engine

[this is the error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJVe9.jpg)

I have a problem when trying to integrate unity with react native using  `@azesmway/react-native-unity`, it says

> Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "React Native Unity View" was not found in the UIManager.

I don't know if the problem is related to the version of unity or react-native.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same error.